# Get data from web query on drop down change in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I had some exceptional requirement. That is i have set of value which will come in the drop down in an Excel cell. While changing the value it will hit the server and  fetch data according the drop down selected in the excel.

Finally i have done with some simple steps. Please find it following.

**Step 1:-** Create your drop down list

Go to Data -> Data validation
[image]

Now you have created a drop down in `F2` cell as follows:

[image]

Now on change we have to create a macro which will fetch data from server:

**Step 2 :-**

[image]

Now you have to click on View Code which will open a code window. There you have to paste the following code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'MsgBox "You just changed " & Target.Address
  If Target.Address = "$F$2" Then

   With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
      "URL;https://www.google.com/", Destination:= _
      Range("A1"))
      .Name = "MR07"
      .FieldNames = True
      .RowNumbers = False
      .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
      .PreserveFormatting = True
      .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
      .BackgroundQuery = True
      .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
      .SavePassword = False
      .SaveData = True
      .AdjustColumnWidth = True
      .RefreshPeriod = 0
      .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
      .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
      .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
      .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
      .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
      .WebDisableDateRecognition = True
      .WebDisableRedirections = True
      .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
      End With
  End If
End Sub
```

In the above code you can replace your own URL instead of https://www.google.com/

`A1` is the starting row of output, which is coming from server. `$F$2` is validating the changes coming from drop down. if you not put this condition for all cell changes it will call this function which is not expected.

Comment: This is very nice! Just a reminder that there is a self-answer option for "Q&A"

Comment: I don't see a question anywhere? Is this more for info? If so, maybe it needs to go to one of the sister SO sights